# What do I need install to use Logs feature in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Pardon as I'm novice ES and Kibana user.
I have kibana which is connected to ElasticSearch instance and index created for my custom data. If I go to discover tab I can see data as expected. If I hit `refresh` I can see number of hits keeps increasing as expected since live data is being sent to ElasticSearch.
[image]
I'm confused how to do I use `Logs` feature in Kibana to see live logs as they come into ElasticSearch. I configured settings for logs to point to my index `fluentd*` but I can not see any logs appearing in console.
Available indices are below

```
green  open .kibana_task_manager_1   Lx2yZknzRseSZyK10DDGfg 1 0    2  1 29.5kb 29.5kb
green  open .apm-agent-configuration qyFmhnaMRCaH6-3M4zSD9g 1 0    0  0   283b   283b
green  open .kibana_1                i8NrtielTQ6Hl_kJ8_uSvA 1 0   26 10 71.2kb 71.2kb
yellow open fluentd                  J4TAQZ9bT-GfRwio7wvo1w 1 1 6108  0    1mb    1mb
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you see in Logs tab?

Comment: I added screenshot to original question

Comment: try to find out all the indices using GET /_cat/indices

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Removed *, still telling me "there are no log messages to display"

Comment: Do you see Stream live button on top right hand side like here https://demo.elastic.co/app/infra#/logs/stream?_g=()&flyoutOptions=(flyoutId:!n,flyoutVisibility:hidden,surroundingLogsId:!n)&logPosition=(position:(tiebreaker:10829385,time:1585959200642),streamLive:!f)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210904/discussion-between-addicted-and-gregory-suvalian).

Answer (score 0):

My logs did not haqve any timestamp and hence no ability to stream logs. Once I added timestamp it started working